# Stumped with JSON returning objects using PHP

Tags: php, json

Am I approaching things correctly here? This is what my iOS developer wants me to do for database values for an app he is working on:

```
{“array”:[{“restID":1, etc.}, {“restID":2, etc.}, {“restID”:3, etc.}, {“restID”:4, etc.}], “error":""}
```

Right now my PHP code is:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sssisi",$lat,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$rest_genre,$eat_options);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rest_id,$user_id,$rest_name,$lat,$lng,$rest_price,$rest_rating,$rest_genre,$eat_options,$result);
    //define error array
    $errArray = array('error' => '');
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $row = array(
            'restID' => $rest_id,
            'userID' => $user_id,
            'rest_name' => $rest_name,
            'lat' => $lat,
            'lng' => $lng,
            'restPrice' => $rest_price,
            'restRating' => $rest_rating,
            'restGenre' => $rest_genre,
            'eat_options' => $eat_options);

         $rows['array'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}....
```

Which outputs the following:

```
{“array”:[{“restID":1, etc.}, {“restID":2, etc.}, {“restID”:3, etc.}, {“restID”:4, etc.}]}
```

Notice I can't fit the array in there otherwise I get some crazy stuff or syntax errors with PHP. Please advise! How can I get the first example to work with the current code I am using? What do I need to manipulate in my PHP? Again, I want

```
{“array”:[{“restID":1, etc.}, {“restID":2, etc.}, {“restID”:3, etc.}, {“restID”:4, etc.}], “error":""}
```

**Not:**

```
{“array”:[{“restID":1, etc.}, {“restID":2, etc.}, {“restID”:3, etc.}, {“restID”:4, etc.}]}
```

Comment: I’m not sure I see the issue. What problem are you having? What syntax errors are you getting?

Comment: Do you want to use array_merge?

Comment: Your examples are confusing as well.

Comment: `echo json_encode(array_merge($rows, $errArray));`

Comment: @Farkie since you already gave the solution, please post it as an answer.

Comment: The syntax errors came about when I tried to do confusing crap like $rows['array'][] = $row.$errArray; or something. I didn't know I could use array_merge()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just merge the error array into the rows array like so:

`echo json_encode(array_merge($rows, $errArray));`

Comment: Thanks Farkie! That's EXACTLY what I needed. Sorry I was so confusing to everyone, I was overcomplicating it because I didn't realize I even  could use the array_merge function.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$rows['error'] = 'Error message'
```

Comment: This was also a correct answer as I could do $rows['array'][] = $row; $rows['error'] .= ''; (append two php strings) and yield the same result. Which is better? To do this or to merge arrays like before?

Comment: put all the returned results in one array, and send it back, using merge function is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You made errArray a separate array that contains one element, a key called error. Your code doesn't add that to the other one which gets encoded as JSON.